# Can "Beziehungsweise" be used as an alternative to "sonst"?

Tags: grammar, difference, word-order

> Komm jetzt aus dem Schlafzimmer heraus und iss, ***beziehungsweise*** wirst du nicht ins DieTotenHosen-Konzert gehen!
>
> Komm jetzt aus dem Schlafzimmer heraus und iss, ***sonst*** wirst du nicht ins DieTotenHosen-Konzert gehen!

Come out of your room now, or else you're not going to the Die Toten Hosen concert!

Can I use ***Beziehungsweise*** instead of ***sonst*** for "or else"

Comment: nope. Sonst - otherwise. Beziehungsweise - respectively.

Comment: Komm jetzt aus dem Schlafzimmer heraus und iss, ***andernfalls*** wirst du nicht ins DieTotenHosen-Kozert!- viel besser? My book says that beziehungsweise means "or else"

Comment: Yes, you can use "andernfalls" instead of "sonst".

Comment: Emanuel, doesn't beziehungsweise mean more that respectively? I'm fairly sure it can also mean "or if not". I like to think of it as a binary XOR operator, meaning Exclusive Or, *only* one or *only* the other
E.g. "Du kannst einen Apfel bzw. einen Tisch haben".

Comment: Wie z.B. " Die Fahrt nach Oregon dauert 10 Stunden, bzw. 2 Tage wenn wir in Yreka übernachten."

Comment: @Ledda It can also mean "or rather" which, however, is close in meaning to "respectively"

Comment: @Ledda...possibly people say that but I'd consider it wrong and imprecise.

Comment: Can you tell us why you thought that it was ok to use *beziehungsweise* here? Your question seems unmotivated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

What your sentence needs is an *or else*, and the best for that is *oder*/*sonst*.

*Beziehungsweise*, other than the fact that it's a tad formal, means *{x}, or, if !{x}, y* -- as your example with the trip to Oregon suggests. The trip is 10 hours (x), or, if !(x), 2 days.